# How to parse JSON String in Android..?

Tags: php, android, json

Hi All I'm calling one php script from my Android code to insert record into the database. On successful insert I'm getting one string in following format-

***{"success":1,"message":"Member registered successfully."}***

And in case of error I'm getting the following string-

**{"success":0,"message":"Oops! An error occurred."}**

Now I wants to parse that string to check whether record is inserted successfully or not for that I have tried following code

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
String strResp=jsonobj.getString("success");
```

but ***strResp*** is getting null..! Please help. Thank you..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code.

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
String strResp = jObj.getString("success");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ } means json object...and [  ] means json array..
```

here,  {"success":1,"message":"Member registered successfully."}  is json object...

so,

```
JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(response);
String  strResp=jsonobj.getString("success");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
String strResp = String.valueOf(jObj.getInt("success"));
```

Because **success** in your json response is int.